# Qu'est-ce qui constitue un mot ?

Tags: élision, lexique, trait-d-union

Parfois, lorsqu'on nous demande d'écrire un texte (que ce soit un article de journal, pour un entretien d'embauche ou à l'école), on précise « votre texte doit contenir environ X mots ».

Je me suis demandé ce qui constituait un mot, en français. Les traitements de texte les définissent comme un groupe de caractères délimités par des espaces et/ou un début/fin de texte.

Est-ce la même définition pour la langue française ?

Dans ce cas, comment se fait-il que *le chien* soient deux mots alors que *l'oiseau* n'en soit qu'un ? Qu'en est-il pour *qu'est-ce* et *d'aujourd'hui* ?

Comment: Si le compte précis est important, ce sont les règles du commanditaire qui valent. Sinon, je pense que tu peux escamoter la réponse à la question dans l'*environ* de la consigne.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dans mes souvenirs scolaires, dans le cadre de l'enseignement du français en France, le trait d'union et l'apostrophe sont considérés comme des séparateurs de mots. Par exemple, « qu'est-ce » et « d'aujourd'hui » comportent tous les deux trois mots. Ceci est corroborré par plusieurs sites sur le résumé comme exercice scolaire en France : [1](http://pcsipsiauxulis.com/spip.php?article29) [2](http://scosta.site.lycee-berthelot.fr/IMG/pdf/METHODE_DE_LA_CONTRACTION_DE_TEXTE.pdf) [3](http://jiheraim-cyberland.chez-alice.fr/2-ressourceslettres_explic/31-coursbts.htm) trouvés sur [une recherche Google](http://www.google.fr/search?q=%22r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9%22+%22nombre+de+mots%22+%22apostrophe%22+%22trait+d%27union%22) ; je n'ai pas vu d'opinion contraire.

Si l'on cherche des sources plus officielles, la [Convention télégraphique internationale de Saint-Pétersbourg](http://www.itu.int/dms_pub/itu-s/oth/02/01/S02010000054002PDFF.pdf) de 1879 précise que les apostrophes et traits d'union sont des séparateurs de mots (article XXIII du Règlement de service international).

D'un point de vue plus académique, une [note de recherche de Guylaine Cochane](http://www.lli.ulaval.ca/fileadmin/llt/fichiers/recherche/revue_LL/vol22/LL22_137_150.pdf) étudie la question plus en détail. Elle conclut son analyse que je ne résumerai pas ici par

> En règle générale, l'apostrophe et le trait d'union sont considérés comme des blancs quand ils servent à unir deux mots. [...] Par exemple *field-free space*, *longueur d'onde*, *main-d'œuvre*, *three-dimensional space* sont formés de trois mots chacun, car chaque élément figure en entrée de dictionnaire. Par contre, *anti-conformisme*, *aujourd'hui*, *pré-industrialisation* ou *semi-nomades* ne représentent qu'un seul mot, les éléments *anti*, *hui*, *pré* et *semi* n'étant pas autonomes.

Comment: Les euphoniques (a-**t**-il, **l'** on a…) ne sont généralement pas considérés comme des mots non plus.

Comment: Le lien 2 est mort. +1 (quand j'ai des votes) pour mentionner les règles extrêmement pointilleuses définies pour les concours des classes préparatoires.

Answer (score 6):

Je ne vois pas de meilleure caractérisation de ce qu'est un mot que sa présence dans un dictionnaire. Un dictionnaire ne donne pas nécessairement la liste de toutes les inflexions, conjugaisons, ou élisions d'un même mot, mais celles-ci ne sont en général pas difficiles à identifier.

Concernant les exemples donnés, on y trouve séparément :

- *le* et *chien*
- *le* et *oiseau*
- *que*, *être* et *ce*
- *de* et *aujourd'hui*

Étymologiquement, le cas de *aujourd'hui* est contestable, mais tel qu'il est utilisé aujourd'hui il s'agit plutôt d'un seul mot, et il y a bien une entrée qui lui correspond dans un dictionnaire.

Pour finir, un mot composé comme *tire-bouchon* est bien comme son nom l'indique un seul mot.

Comment: Comment est-ce que le nom de *tire-bouchon* il indique comme un seul mot?

Comment: @Jez: Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre la question. Je disais qu'un mot composé est un seul mot. Les amateurs de détails sordides pourront en trouver [ici](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot_compos%C3%A9).

Comment: Généralement, quand on se pose la question, c'est parce que des détails sordides importent à quelqu'un, et qu'on veut savoir lesquels ; à partir de là, la liste du dictionnaire ne me semble pas répondre à ces interogations.

Comment: Je précise que je donne là une réponse à « qu'est-ce qui définit ce qu'est un mot » indépendament de tout compte arbitraire défini pour les examens et autres textes de longeur limitée.

Comment: Sans doute (2 ?), mais est-ce qu'il n'y aurait pas une entrée à « pomme de terre », dans un dictionnaire ?

Answer (score 3):

Les logiciels de traitement de texte sont surtout créés par des anglophones pour des anglophones… et en anglais, l'apostrophe signifie généralement une contraction – deux mots qui n'en forment plus qu'un, grammaticalement. En français, ce n'est pas le cas, et il me semble qu'il s'agit d'une erreur logicielle.

En ce qui concerne les tirets, c'est le même problème.

Un correcteur spécialisé pour la langue française me donne, en revanche, un résultat correct. "Le chien" (2), "l'oiseau" (2), "qu'est-ce" (3), "arc-en-ciel" (3) et "aujourd'hui" (2) – ce dernier me semble plus discutable, mais étymologiquement acceptable.

Comment: Donc les mots sont séparés par des espaces, des apostrophes ou des traits d'union ? (Sauf sans doute une exception qui confirme la règle).

Comment: @Oltarus Par des espaces, des apostrophes et parfois des traits d'union (comme le dit Stéphane Gimenez, un mot composé est un seul mot, même si les correcteurs orthographiques ne le voient pas toujours ainsi). Mieux vaut ne pas accorder trop de confiance aux logiciels pour cela…

Comment: +1 pour « si le compte précis importe, ne pas faire confiance aux logiciels ».